# Adding data in rows to columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
     wk Brand Retail_price
1     1     a          1.2
2     2     a          1.3
3     1     c          1.4
4     2     c          1.5
5     1     d          1.6
6     2     d          1.7
```

I am trying to get the retail price of other brands during the same week as columns. 
I want to get to:

```
     wk Brand Retail_price Retail_price_a Retail_price_c Retail_price_d
1     1     a          1.2             NA            1.4            1.6
2     2     a          1.3             NA            1.5            1.7
3     1     c          1.4            1.2             NA            1.6
4     2     c          1.5            1.3             NA            1.7
5     1     d          1.6            1.2            1.4             NA  
6     2     d          1.7            1.3            1.5             NA
```

I have tried looping through the data to manually add columns for each brand. Turned out to be very inefficient.

I am new to R. I am thinking of something equivalent to `pd.pivot` in python, create a new `df` and then join the two.

How can I do this in R? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you want to check the `merge()` function I think it'll get you rolling.You would key your merge by wk and brand, and you should be able to find existing questions to help with the right syntax.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Here is a `dput` result with the data in the question: `structure(list(wk = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Brand = c("a", 
"a", "c", "c", "d", "d"), Retail.Price = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
1.6, 1.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))`

Comment: `merge()` with `dcast()` worked !

Comment: @SurajNagabhushanaPonnaganti For future questions, you should do what @r2evans suggested, you should use `dput`: `dput(df)`. This would output the results in my comment. This will enable others to easily reproduce your code. You can still show the output like you already have, in addition.

Comment: yes! will do. Wasn't aware of this. Is this R specific? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a combination of reshaping (long-to-wide) and merge. Here's an example using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
# data
x <- data.frame(
  wk = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
  Brand = c("a", "a", "c", "c", "d", "d"),
  Price = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x2 <- spread(x, Brand, Price, sep = "_") %>%
  left_join(x, by = "wk")
x2
#   wk Brand_a Brand_c Brand_d Brand Price
# 1  1     1.2     1.4     1.6     a   1.2
# 2  1     1.2     1.4     1.6     c   1.4
# 3  1     1.2     1.4     1.6     d   1.6
# 4  2     1.3     1.5     1.7     a   1.3
# 5  2     1.3     1.5     1.7     c   1.5
# 6  2     1.3     1.5     1.7     d   1.7
```

You can then work on removing same-brand cells if needed.

In `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
xDT <- setDT(copy(x))

merge(xDT, dcast(xDT, wk ~ Brand), by = c("wk"))
# or #
xDT[dcast(xDT, wk ~ Brand), on = c("wk")]
```

Comment: ```left_join(x,., by = "wk")``` This would be more like OP's output. Not that it matters tho.

Comment: In order to get the `NA` values in the columns as OP suggested, one could do something like the following to the `x2`: `x2 %>% gather(Brand.Name, Brand.Price, -c(wk, Brand, Price)) %>%
  mutate(Brand.Price = ifelse(paste0("Brand_", Brand) == Brand.Name, NA, Brand.Price)) %>%
  spread(Brand.Name, Brand.Price) %>% arrange(Brand, wk)`